# Rotating spite not showing

Tags: python, image, rotation, pygame, sprite

I tried to let the "Player" rotate. It's a picture of the head that needs to be rotateable. But the error is that the head is not displaying (Player is not displaying). The image (bigshaghoofdz.png) needs to be rotateable.
It is rotatable by pressing the K_UP en the K_DOWN. Can turn a full 360 degrees. In the end it needs to shoot lasers from its eyes.

```
import pygame
import random
import math
GRAD = math.pi / 180

class Config(object):
    fullscreen = False
    width = 640
    height = 360
    fps = 60

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    maxrotate = 360 
    down = (pygame.K_DOWN)
    up = (pygame.K_UP)
    number = 1

    def __init__(self, startpos = (-1,223), angle=0):
        self.number = Player.number
        Player.number += 1
        Player.book[self.number] = self
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.pos = [startpos[-1], startpos[223]]
        self.down = Player.down[self.number]
        self.up = Player.up[self.number]

        image = pygame.image.load('BigShagHoofdz.png')

    def update(self, seconds):

        pressedkeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()          

        self.turndirection = 0 
        if pressedkeys[self.down]:
            self.turndirection -= 1
        if pressedkeys[self.up]:
            self.turndirection += 1

#end classes
#defs

def radians_to_degrees(radians):
    return (radians / math.pi) * 180.0

def degrees_to_radians(degrees):
    return degrees * (math.pi / 180.0)

def main():
    #game 
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((Config.width,Config.height))
    background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')

    background = background.convert()
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = Config.fps
    playtime = 0

    Playergroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allgroup = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

    Player.groups = Playergroup, allgroup

    mainloop = True
    while mainloop:
        millisecond = clock.tick(Config.fps)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mainloop = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    mailoop = False 

        pygame.display.set_caption("say hi")
        allgroup.clear(screen, background)
        allgroup.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment the angle if a key gets pressed, then transform the original image, assign it to the `self.image` attribute and get a new rect with the center of the old rect.

```
import pygame


class Config(object):
    fullscreen = False
    width = 640
    height = 360
    fps = 60

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    maxrotate = 360
    down = (pygame.K_DOWN)
    up = (pygame.K_UP)

    def __init__(self, startpos=(100,223), angle=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = list(startpos)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((70, 70), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), (35, 35), 35)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('black'), (35, 15), 8)
        self.orig_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=startpos)
        self.angle = angle

    def update(self, seconds):
        pressedkeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressedkeys[self.down]:
            self.angle -= 2
            self.rotate_image()
        if pressedkeys[self.up]:
            self.angle += 2
            self.rotate_image()

    def rotate_image(self):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((Config.width,Config.height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = Config.fps
    allgroup = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    player = Player()
    allgroup.add(player)

    mainloop = True
    while mainloop:
        millisecond = clock.tick(Config.fps)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mainloop = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    mailoop = False

        allgroup.update(millisecond)

        screen.fill((50, 50, 70))
        allgroup.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Works, Great thanks. I added my image to the self.image